# change background color of lightning tab LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

LWC don't allow to change color with css and there document guide don't say anything about this ?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tab/documentation

Can anyone help here?

Comment: You want to change the color of tab itself, or its contents?

Comment: background color to tabset, tab itself not content